# How do I map array of images from firebase to react-native image?

Tags: react-native

I have an array in firebase with image url values.

```
  "image" : [ "https://assets.s3.amazonaws.com/1586862746143.png", "https://onpro-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/1586862746882.png", "https://onpro-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/1586862747012.png", "https://onpro-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/1586862747587.png" ],
```

I'd like to map these images in my react-native application.

I did `console.log(image);`
and it returns array like so.

```
Array [
  "https://onpro-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/1586864223105.png",
  "https://onpro-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/1586864223604.png",
  "https://onpro-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/1586864223723.png",
]
```

I wrote a map function for my image like so:

```js
<Text style={styles.imageText}> Images: </Text>
image.map((x, i) => <Image
  key={i}
  style={{ borderRadius: 20, width: 100, height: 120, top: 35 }}
  source={{ uri: x }}
/>
```

However it says variable x cannot be found, what am I doing wrong?

Error image:
[image]

Comment: Can you share screenshot of error?

Comment: I've attached error screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forgot the brackets.

Try this

```
<Text style={styles.imageText}> Images: </Text>
{
    image.map((x, i) => (
        <Image
            key="i"
            style={{ borderRadius: 20, width: 100, height: 120, top: 35 }}
            source={{ uri: x }}
        />
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank  you! This gets rid of the variable error however the images are not being rendered, any ideas? Console log shows appropriate urls.

Comment: @MikkKüttim I can't open those images in browser. I receive access denied error. This might be the same error in your RN app.

Comment: I tried to open the images link on browser and it gives an error

Comment: I've updated the urls, that was my bad hence you received error denied.

Comment: @MikkKüttim did you forget to add bucket name to images url? However, this is not a react-native issue now. Read this: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=62835

Comment: The images are now visible, had to restart my app, thank you all!